# div grid inside div grid

Tags: html, css

For hours and hours I've trying to get the style as I wanted. I'm trying to get the grid inside the grid for example like this

```
 _______________________________________
|  _______________  |  _______________  |
| |               | | |               | |
| |_______________| | |_______________| |
| |       |       | | |       |       | |
| |_______|_______| | |_______|_______| |
|___________________|___________________|
```

and this is the code I put following

```
 <div class="grid">
  <div class="column">
    <h2><?php echo $title; ?></h2>
    
    <div class="editgrid">
 <div class="editcolumn">
  <?php echo $row_text['box_1']; ?>
 </div>
</div>

 <br/>

<div class="editgrid_2">
 <div class="editcolumn">
  <?php echo $row_text['box_2']; ?>
 </div>
 <div class="editcolumn">
  <?php echo $row_text['box_3']; ?>
 </div>
</div>

   </div>
```

and this is the css I am using

```
    .editcolumn {
      background-color: white;
      padding: 1em 2em;
      border-radius: 25px;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    
    .editgrid {
      display: grid;
      grid-column-gap: 20px;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
    }
    
    .editgrid_2 {
      display: grid;
      grid-column-gap: 20px;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    }
        
    .column {
      background-color: white;
      padding: 1em 2em;
      text-align: left;
      border-radius: 25px;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }

    .grid {
      display: grid;
      grid-column-gap: 20px;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    }
```

but unfortunately is look like this which I do not plan it.

```
 _______________________________
|                               |
|_______________________________|
|              | |              |
|______________| |______________|
 _______________________________
|               |               |
|               |               |
|               |               |
|               |               |
|               |               |
|_______________|_______________|
```

What am I missing? Any help would be grateful

Comment: try to build this as one grid - not a grid inside a grid - first to reduce the complexity (and also not run into support problems at front). if it helps you can also mock this easily with HTML tables. it may spare you a ton of CSS and a bit of HTML even.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your code works?

I changed the `grid` css to have a background of red to make things more visible, it seems you only have 1 column? If you add another column, like your first in your desired image, It should work.

I also removed the php references and just hard coded a `<h4>` tag instead.

Check out https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-cache-fg4ml9?file=/src/App.js

Full code:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div class="grid">
        <div class="column">
          <div class="editgrid">
            <div class="editcolumn">
              <h4>'hello'</h4>
            </div>
          </div>

          <br />

          <div class="editgrid_2">
            <div class="editcolumn">
              <h4>'hello'</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="editcolumn">
              <h4>'hello'</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="column">
          <div class="editgrid">
            <div class="editcolumn">
              <h4>'hello'</h4>
            </div>
          </div>

          <br />

          <div class="editgrid_2">
            <div class="editcolumn">
              <h4>'hello'</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="editcolumn">
              <h4>'hello'</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Links can die over time, please try to use an example code block instead of only a codesandbox link.

Comment: Roger that @ethry

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. I used `flex-box` more because it's kinda easier to work with flex if you ask me.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.main-wrapper {
    margin: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto;
    text-align: justify;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0 10px;
}

.hero {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.grid>section {
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.grid>section>div {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.grid>section>div>p {
    padding: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .main-wrapper {
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .grid {
        margin: 10px 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="main-wrapper">
        <section class="grid">
            <div class="hero">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            </div>
            <section>
                <div class="div-one">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quis corporis consectetur inventore,
                        animi
                        cumque iure consequuntur saepe reprehenderit beatae exercitationem.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quis corporis consectetur inventore,
                        animi
                        cumque iure consequuntur saepe reprehenderit beatae exercitationem.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="div-two">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quis corporis consectetur inventore,
                        animi
                        cumque iure consequuntur saepe reprehenderit beatae exercitationem.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quis corporis consectetur inventore,
                        animi
                        cumque iure consequuntur saepe reprehenderit beatae exercitationem.</p>
                </div>
            </section>
        </section>
        <section class="grid">
            <div class="hero">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            </div>

            <section>
                <div class="div-one">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quis corporis consectetur inventore,
                        animi
                        cumque iure consequuntur saepe reprehenderit beatae exercitationem.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quis corporis consectetur inventore,
                        animi
                        cumque iure consequuntur saepe reprehenderit beatae exercitationem.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="div-two">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quis corporis consectetur inventore,
                        animi
                        cumque iure consequuntur saepe reprehenderit beatae exercitationem.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quis corporis consectetur inventore,
                        animi
                        cumque iure consequuntur saepe reprehenderit beatae exercitationem.</p>
                </div>
            </section>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

After all I done fixing this div. But now here's comes the other problem. I don't seems to know how I can get this either BBCode or the html code to show? this is the editpage.php

```
<?php
require_once('pagestyle.php');

/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","********","********");

// Check connection
if($con === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

   $id = !isset($_GET['id'])?"":$_GET['id'];
    $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM templates WHERE id='$id'")or die(mysqli_error());
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    
    $title = htmlspecialchars($row["title"]);
    $title_de = htmlspecialchars($row["title_de"]);
   
?>
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
 <head>
    <style>
        .editcolumn { background-color: white; padding: 1em 2em; border-radius: 10px; border: 1px solid black; }
        .editgrid { display: grid; grid-column-gap: 20px; grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr); }
        .editgrid_2 { display: grid; grid-column-gap: 20px; grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr); }
        .editgrid_3 { display: grid; grid-column-gap: 20px; grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); }
        .column { background-color: white; padding: 1em 2em; text-align: left; border-radius: 10px; border: 1px solid black; }
        .grid { display: grid; grid-column-gap: 20px; grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr); }
    </style>
 </head>
 <body>

 <div class="grid">
  <div class="column">
    <h2><?php echo $title; ?></h2>
    
    <?php echo strip_tags($itwork, '<div><br>'); ?>

   </div>

  <div class="column">
    <h2><?php echo $title_de; ?></h2>
    
    <?php echo strip_tags($itwork_de, '<div><br>'); ?>

   </div>
 </div>
   
 </body>
</html>
```

and this is the pagestyle.php

```
<?php
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","********","********");

// Check connection
if($con === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

   $id = !isset($_GET['id'])?"":$_GET['id'];
   //Select Query from templates
    $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM templates WHERE id='$id'")or die(mysqli_error());
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    
   //Select Query from text_box
    $query_text = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM text_box WHERE id='$id'")or die(mysqli_error());
    $row_text = mysqli_fetch_array($query_text);
    

if (htmlspecialchars($row['pagestyle'] == '4')){ 

 $itwork = '<div class="editgrid"><div class="editcolumn">
    '.htmlspecialchars_decode($row_text["box_1"]).'
    </div></div><br/><div class="editgrid_2"><div class="editcolumn">
    '.htmlspecialchars_decode($row_text["box_2"]).'
    </div><div class="editcolumn">
    '.htmlspecialchars_decode($row_text["box_3"]).' 
    </div></div>';
    
  $itwork_de = '<div class="editgrid"><div class="editcolumn">
    '.htmlspecialchars($row_text["box_1de"]).'
    </div></div><br/><div class="editgrid_2"><div class="editcolumn">
    '.htmlspecialchars($row_text["box_2de"]).'
    </div><div class="editcolumn">
    '.htmlspecialchars($row_text["box_3de"]).' 
    </div></div>';
 
}

?>
```

So far looks all good. But unfortunately I can't get this right. As you can see on the screenshot. Either BBCode or html code will show like this.

I also did try searching for this problem and no matter what I found they all still like this or it will show blank page.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHEee.jpg)

Comment: Your Answer appears to be more information to the original question. It's better to add it to the original question rather than create a new Answer.